# Why its saying 0 arguments passed

Tags: ruby

What's wrong with this ruby program?

```
def makecassrole(ingredients)
  puts "I am #{ingredients}"
  yield(ingredients)
end

makecassrole do |ingredients|
  puts "Preheat ovent o 375 degree"
  puts "Place #{ingredients} in dish"
  puts "Bake for 20 min"
end

makecassrole("noodles, celeray,and tuna")
```

**It's giving me below error**

```
C:/Users/akathaku/mars2/LearningRuby/rubyblock.rb:1:in `makecassrole': wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) (ArgumentError)
    from C:/Users/akathaku/mars2/LearningRuby/rubyblock.rb:6:in `<main>'
```

I think I am passing 1 argument when calling this method. Why is it saying 0 arguments passed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ruby, arguments and blocks are different. Read more about the differences here: http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html
This can be handled in two ways.

One approach can be passing the  argument even when you are passing a block:

```
def makecassrole(ingredients)
  if block_given?
    yield(ingredients)
  else
    puts "I am #{ingredients}"
  end
end

makecassrole('you need to pass some ingredient here') do |ingredients|
  puts "Preheat ovent o 375 degree"
  puts "Place #{ingredients} in dish"
  puts "Bake for 20 min"
end

makecassrole("noodles, celeray,and tuna")
```

Second approach (more preferred in my opinion) is to make the argument optional (default arguments):

```
def makecassrole(ingredients='some default argument')
  if block_given?
    yield(ingredients)
  else
    puts "I am #{ingredients}"
  end
end

makecassrole do |ingredients|
  puts "Preheat ovent o 375 degree"
  puts "Place #{ingredients} in dish"
  puts "Bake for 20 min"
end

makecassrole("noodles, celeray,and tuna")
```

Here we have `'some default argument'` for the method `makecasserole`.

***NOTE***: It is important to check for `block_given?` before you `yield` else it will fail when you don't pass in a block (as you do the second time you call the method).

Comment: This: "Your method does not accept a block." is wrong. It does accept.

Comment: @sawa Right. Edited the answer. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 0):

Before calling it with one argument, you calling it with zero argument (and a block) here:

```
makecassrole do |ingredients|
  puts "Preheat ovent o 375 degree"
  puts "Place #{ingredients} in dish"
  puts "Bake for 20 min"
end
```

Comment: where can you please help me and show where I am wrong

Comment: On line 6 of your example code (as per your question). The `makecassrole do ...` is calling your function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're over-complicating this, unless you were trying to test out `yield`.

You need to first pass it `ingredients` because that is a required argument, and then you can pass it a block to use `yield`. Also, it looks like you want to pass each food item separately, so maybe use an array and iterate over it.

```
def makecassrole(ingredients)
  ingredients.each do |ingredient|
    puts "I am #{ingredient}"
    yield(ingredient)
  end
end

makecassrole(["noodles", "celeray", "tuna"]) do |i|
  puts "Prehead oven to 375 degrees"
  puts "Place #{i} in dish"
  puts "Bake for 20 min"
end
```

Instead of using yield, I think if you used one method with all the text inside and iterate over the ingredients to print out everything for each ingredient would be a lot simpler.